# python - print a csv row into a HTML column

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to print the data of a CSV column into an HTML table

CSV file is like this (sample)

```
firstname, surname
firstname, surname
firstname, surname
firstname, surname
firstname, surname
firstname, surname
firstname, surname
```

I can read this data in ok - and get it to print out into a table via the following:

```
import csv
import sys
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

#load in csv file
data = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]))

names = ""

#Read column names from first line of the file
fields = data.next()
for row in data:
    names = row[0] + " " + row[1]
    html_row = " <tr> "
    html_col = " <td border=0 width=15%>" + names + "</td></tr>"
    html_out = html_out + html_row + html_col 


html = html_header + html_out + html_footer
print html
pdf.write_html(html)
pdf.output('test2.pdf', 'F')
```

this gives the following:

```
<tr><td border=0 width=15%>firstname surname</td></tr>
<tr><td border=0 width=15%>firstname surname</td></tr>
<tr><td border=0 width=15%>firstname surname</td></tr>
```

ie - every name is on a separate row - what i'd like to do is have every name as a cell column cell

```
<tr><td border=0 width=15%>firstname surname</td><td border=0 width=15%>firstname surname</td><td border=0 width=15%>firstname surname</td></tr>
```

thanks

Comment: Is it possible that you are missing an indentation on line `html_out = html_out + ....`, bc currently it is not part of the loop which wouldn't give you the result shown in your question?

Comment: bad formatting on my part there - should be fixed now..

Comment: Also `html_rowend` is not set anywhere in the shown code. so does this run as shown?

Comment: removed now - was left over when trying to format the example

Answer (score 0):

Some variables in sample are not set, but this is due to reducing of sample to aminimal size I guess, so if you fill in these details, the following should work (suboptimal if more than 7 entries due to the hardcoded 15% width on the html td element.

```
import csv
import sys
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

# load in csv file
data = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1]))

# Read column names from first line of the file to ignore them
fields = data.next()
```

Below the loop from question has been replaced by a list comprehension.
cell_att holds the given attributes of the table cell elements and it will be interpolated like row[0] and row[1] into the strings making up the html_out list.

```
cell_att = " border=0 width=15%"
row_data = ["<td%s>%s %s</td>" % (cell_att, row[0], row[1]) for row in data]
```

Here one simply joins all cells and injects into a html table row element:

```
html_out = "<tr>" + "".join(row_data) + "</tr>"

html = html_header + html_out + html_footer
print html
pdf.write_html(html)
pdf.output('test2.pdf', 'F')
```

The other answers also give IMO useful hints esp. on the styling level of the HTML. In case you later decide to digest / transform more than 7 names, the above code might be a good start to create rows with at most 7 cells or to adapt the width attribute value by minor modifications.

Answer (score -1):

You only need one `<tr>` to make a single row.

```css
table, td {
  border: solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>firstname surname</td>
        <td>firstname surname</td>
        <td>firstname surname</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In order to make this work in your code, you need to create you row outside the loop:

```
html_row = '<tr>' # open row

for row in data:
    names = row[0] + " " + row[1]
    # append columns to the row
    html_row += "<td border=0 width=15%>" + names + "</td>"

html_row += '</tr>' # close row

html_out = html_row
```